# When did the first on-screen bite occur on The Walking Dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie, fear-the-walking-dead

I'm rewatching the first two episodes of *Fear the Walking Dead*, and I just realized that you don't really see anyone being bitten in either episode, except perhaps in a shaky video taken from a helicopter, but even then, the bite is merely suggested, and it is possible that no bite actually took place.

That made me wonder when we saw the first instance of a zombie biting a human in the original *The Walking Dead* series.

When was the first bite on *The Walking Dead*?

Comment: [snip] - Take it to chat, guys

Comment: Or don't.  I'd suggest that.

Comment: Pretty sure the helicopter video shows a bite or two.  And while I suppose not actually shown, Gloria is totally biting that dude.  And we see a bite injury on Matt, though not the actual bite.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - I don't think we actually **see** Gloria biting him, and the helicopter video was the "implied" bite I mentioned.  Matt doesn't count, because we only see the aftermath.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - I see why you were confused - question edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer appears to be Carol's husband Ed, who was the first one bitten during the walker attack in Season One episode "Vatos."

[From the wiki:](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Vatos_(Episode))

> Ed, meanwhile, hears rustling outside his tent. He thinks it's Carol bugging him to join the group, and unzips the flap to yell at her, but instead he finds a walker. It topples him, biting his neck as more walkers swarm in.

Comment: Yeah, that's way before the ones I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(TV_series)) on Wiki Dale was bitten

> By that walker that killed him, but as I remember it, it was more of a disembowelling where the walker used it's fingers to pull apart his chest like it was clay (suggesting Walkers have crazy finger strength.

As I don't remember it that way, I'd go with Hershels leg being the first example of a walker sinking its teeth into a human on screen.

Or even earlier would be Otis and Shane, but I don't think they actually show Walkers chomping on Otis.

Comment: I doubt Dale was the first. He wasn't bitten until the second season.

Comment: That's what I thought when going through the season summaries. Season one was really short though. If anyone was bitten on screen during those episodes they must have been a forgettable character

Comment: I can think of several characters who were bitten in the first season:  Amy (on screen), Jim (off screen), Ed (on), and several people in non-speaking roles in the camp.  I'm having more trouble trying to remember bitings in season two prior to Dale, but I know at least one of the thugs at the bar was bitten, but Otis was devoured in the second or third episode.